# What is session leader in `ps ax`

Tags: linux, bash, unix, process

See the command bellow

```
# ps ax | grep bitlbee
 2271 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/bitlbee -s mysql -c /root/config.conf
 3930 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/bitlbee -s mysql -c /root/config.conf
```

See the STAT column. Here is the explanation

```
S    Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
s    is a session leader
```

What is **session leader** here? Also what is **session** here? How do I know which of these 2 process is active?

Comment: See [What are “session leaders” in `ps`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18166/5355) at Unix&Linux SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [The Linux Kernel: Processes](http://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html#ss10.3):

> **10.3 Sessions**
>
> Every process group is in a unique session. (When the process is created, it becomes a member of the session of its parent.) By convention, the session ID of a session equals the process ID of the first member of the session, called the session leader. A process finds the ID of its session using the system call getsid().
>
> Every session may have a controlling tty, that then also is called the controlling tty of each of its member processes. A file descriptor for the controlling tty is obtained by opening /dev/tty. (And when that fails, there was no controlling tty.) Given a file descriptor for the controlling tty, one may obtain the SID using tcgetsid(fd).

As to your last question

> How do I know which of these 2 process is active?

Given that both processes are sleeping, the answer is "neither".